# I am getting an error message that I don't know how to fix

Tags: c

I am getting this error message:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'Nombre {aka struct <anonymous>}' from type 'int':
nombre[0] = 'A'+(rand()%26);
```

The code:

```
typedef struct{
  char nombre[9];
}Nombre;

Nombre* crearNombre(){
    Nombre *nombre;
    nombre = (Nombre*)malloc(9* sizeof(char));
    nombre[0] = 'A'+(rand()%26);
    for (int i=1; i<9; ++i){
        if(i == 9){
            nombre[i] = '\0';
        }
        else nombre[i] = 'a'+(rand()%26);
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you hoping `nombre[0]` refers to? The `nombre` pointer in this context represents a `Nombre` struct, not the `nombre[9]` character array within one of these structs.

Comment: @Nico Welcome to SO! Please choose a title that describes your technical problem that others might search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nombre` is a pointer to the structure `Nombre`, so `nombre[0]` is the structure, not an integer.

You should allocate correct size and refer the member `nombre` to access the elements.

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  char nombre[9];
}Nombre;

Nombre* crearNombre(){
    Nombre *nombre;
    nombre = malloc(sizeof(*nombre));
    if (nombre == NULL) return NULL;
    nombre->nombre[0] = 'A'+(rand()%26);
    for (int i=1; i<9; ++i){
        nombre->nombre[i] = 'a'+(rand()%26);
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

One more point: I removed the `if(i == 9)` statement because `i` will never be `9` under the loop condition `i < 9`.

Comment: Also, use more detailed naming,  You might not have confused yourself if you had used `NombreStruct *nombre_struct;` then you might see that you needed `nombre_struct->nombre`